# Display Query results in infowindow

Tags: infowindow, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to display the query results in an Infowindow with a click on my map. But the infowindow displaying on a second click not with a firstclick on map.

Can you run the following code and suggest where I have to modify the code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.17/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.17/"></script>
    <script>
      var map;

      require(["esri/map", "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer", "esri/tasks/QueryTask", "esri/tasks/query", "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol", "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol", "esri/InfoTemplate", "dojo/_base/Color", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, QueryTask, Query, SimpleFillSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, InfoTemplate, Color) {
        map = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "topo",  //For full list of pre-defined basemaps, navigate to http://arcg.is/1JVo6Wd
          center: [-100.275, 42.573], // longitude, latitude
          zoom: 5
        });

        var dynamicMapService = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer")
        map.addLayer(dynamicMapService);

        var queryTask = new QueryTask("https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/1");
        var query = new Query();
        query.returnGeometry = true;
        query.outFields = ["*"];

        var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("${*}");

        var symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
            new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
              new Color([255, 0, 0]), 2), new Color([255, 255, 0, 0.25]))

        map.on("click", executeQueryTask);

        function executeQueryTask(evt){

        query.geometry = evt.mapPoint;      
        queryTask.execute(query, showResults);

        }
        function showResults(featureSet) {
          //remove all graphics on the maps graphics layer
          map.graphics.clear();

          //Performance enhancer - assign featureSet array to a single variable.
          var resultFeatures = featureSet.features;

          //Loop through each feature returned
          for (var i=0, il=resultFeatures.length; i<il; i++) {
            //Get the current feature from the featureSet.
            //Feature is a graphic
            var graphic = resultFeatures[i];
            graphic.setSymbol(symbol);

            //Set the infoTemplate.
            graphic.setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate);

            //Add graphic to the map graphics layer.
            map.graphics.add(graphic);
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

map.infoWindow actually is Popup. if you check link , you see show function. you can use show function in your code.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/popup-amd.html#show

for example : change showResults function

```
function showResults(featureSet) {

    var features = featureSet.features.map(function(feature){return 
        feature.setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate)
    })
    map.infoWindow.setFeatures(features);
    features.length>0 ? map.infoWindow.show(features[0].geometry.getCentroid()) : console.log("not found");


}
```